# Abstract Algebra: G is Abelian, $H:= \{x \in G : \lvert x\rvert \text{ is odd} \}$ Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

I'm trying to write this proof, but can't seem to finish it. I've tried to suppose that $a,b \in H$ and

$$ |a| = 2k+1 $$
$$ |b| = 2n+1 $$

with $n,k \in 2\mathbb{N}$. I also know that $|b^{-1}| = |b|$ so I tried

$$ (a)^{2k+1}(b^{-1})^{2n+1} = e $$
Suppose WLOG that $k < n$, and use the fact that $G$ is abelian. Then

$$ (ab^{-1})^{2k+1}(b^{-1})^{2(n-k)} = e $$

At which point I am stuck. I want to have

$$ (ab^{-1})^{2k+1} = e $$

But I have an even number of left-over $b^{-1}$ to deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of a product $ab$ in an abelian group is a divisor of the least common multiple of the orders of $a$ and $b$, i.e., ${\rm ord}(ab)\mid {\rm lcm}(({\rm ord}(a),{\rm ord}(b))$, see here:

[Order of product of two elements in a group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67180/order-of-product-of-two-elements-in-a-group)

Let $m={\rm ord}(a), n={\rm ord}(b)$, and $d={\rm ord}(ab)$. Then
$$d|\frac{mn}{\gcd(m,n)}=\text{lcm}(m,n),\quad\frac{mn}{\gcd(m,n)^2}|d.$$

Furthermore the least common multiple of two odd numbers is odd:

[Is the lowest common multiple of two odd numbers, an odd number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216623/is-the-lowest-common-multiple-of-two-odd-numbers-an-odd-number)

Comment: Unfortunately, the claim about the lcm only holds if the subgroups generated by the elements intersect trivially, otherwise it may happen that one just gets a divisor in that (which still suffices for this purpose, as it will still be odd).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, you are right, thank you.I replaced the incorrect link; I will be more careful next time.